# Managing Azure AAD Applications with Microsoft Graph

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I want to renew Azure AAD Application Secret (Key) with C# and rest api. Which Graph API (developer.microsoft.com) I should be using.

Also, can I call the rest API with Application Authentication? as I need to run it as a background job. To set a new secret, does application need to have any access and how can I set these for application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use *Azure AD Graph API* for application and service principal management.
While AAD Graph is being deprecated,
these features are still in beta on Microsoft Graph API.
They have had major changes lately in the beta endpoint and I would not recommend using that.

For C# you can use this library: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient/

Yes, you can use Client Credentials flow to authenticate.
Creating secrets is a highly-privileged operation however, and you may need to assign an administrator role on the service principal of your app.
You can do this using PowerShell, e.g. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aaddevsup/2018/08/29/how-to-add-an-azure-ad-role-to-a-enterprise-application-service-principal/.
Application Administrator might be enough for this, though I have not tested it.

Do note that your app will not be able to update its own secret if it has expired ;)

Comment: Hi @juunas Which AAD Graph API I should be using for adding a key for application? A Sample payload should be helpful.